# Reinstall OS X for older MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, formatting

I have an older MacBook Pro (Mid 2009) that cannot start and need to reinstall OS X from USB key or disc. With another MacBook I tried to download OS X El Capitan but is not available, only macOS Sierra, but my laptop is too old for macOS Sierra. How can download OS X El Capitan or older version of OS X?

Answer (score 1):

You can download OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 (6.21 GB) [via this link](https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12), which will open first in the Browser, then in the App Store.app.

> OS X El Capitan
>
> This version of OS X El Capitan is for users running OS X Snow Leopard
>   who would like to upgrade to macOS Sierra. If you are running Snow
>   Leopard and would like to upgrade to Sierra, you need to install El
>   Capitan first. This version of El Capitan can also be installed on Mac
>   computers that are not comparable with Sierra.

[image]

Comment: not work, same message...there is nothing left to do but throw it in the trash?